# Query string selections for XLS spreadsheet C#

Tags: c#, database, xls, data-conversion

I am trying to grab cells in XLS spreadsheets, assign them to string arrays, then manipulate the data and export to multiple CVS files.

The trouble is the XLS spreadsheet contains information that is not relevant, useable data doesn't start till row 17 and columns have no headings with just the default Sheet1.

I have looked at related questions and tried figuring it out myself with no success. The following code to read the XLS kinda works but is messy to work with as the row lengths vary from one XLS file to another and it is automatically pulling empty columns and rows.

**CODE**

```
public static void xlsReader()
        {
            string fileName = string.Format("{0}\\LoadsAvailable.xls", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";" + @"Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";


            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                int counter = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Line " + counter + ":" + reader[28].ToString()); // Just for testing
                    counter++;
                }
            }

        }
```

---

I could do a bunch of trickery with loops to get the data that is required but there has to be a query string that could get the data from row 17 with only 8 columns(not 26 columns with 18 empty)?

I have tried many query string examples and can not seam to get any to work with a starting row index or filter out the empty data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a handy method that converts an excel file to a flat file.

You may want to change the connection string properties to suit your needs. I needed headers for my case.

Note you will need the Access database engine installed on your machine. I needed the 32 bit version since the app i dev'd was 32 bit. I bet you will also need it.

I parameterized the delimiter for the flat file, because I had cases where I didn't need a comma but a pipe symbol.

How to call method ex: `ConvertExcelToFlatFile(openFileName, savePath, '|'); // pipe delimited`

```
// Converts Excel To Flat file
    private void ConvertExcelToFlatFile(string excelFilePath, string csvOutputFile, char delimeter, int worksheetNumber = 1)
    {

        if (!File.Exists(excelFilePath)) throw new FileNotFoundException(excelFilePath);
        if (File.Exists(csvOutputFile)) throw new ArgumentException("File exists: " + csvOutputFile);

        // connection string
        var cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml; IMEX=1; HDR=NO\"", excelFilePath);
        var cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnnStr);

        // get schema, then data
        var dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            var schemaTable = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            if (schemaTable.Rows.Count < worksheetNumber) throw new ArgumentException("The worksheet number provided cannot be found in the spreadsheet");
            string worksheet = schemaTable.Rows[worksheetNumber - 1]["table_name"].ToString().Replace("'", "");
            string sql = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", worksheet);

            var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            // free resources
            cnn.Close();
        }

        // write out CSV data
        using (var wtr = new StreamWriter(csvOutputFile)) // disposes file handle when done
        {

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(row.ItemArray.ToString());
                bool firstLine = true;
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    // skip the first line the initial 
                    if (!firstLine)
                    {
                        wtr.Write(delimeter);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        firstLine = false;
                    }

                    var data = row[col.ColumnName].ToString();//.Replace("\"", "\"\""); // replace " with ""
                    wtr.Write(String.Format("{0}", data));
                }
                wtr.WriteLine();
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Tried this and works great! I changed the connection string and delimiter and produced results. Guess there is no way around the trickery to clean the white space and hundreds of delimiters of empty cells. Thanks for your help and know I am on the correct path now.

Comment: @abflett No problem. This solution took me awhile to figure out. Can you give me the plus rep and the answer?? Thanks!